# отследить div class и data в javascript (jquery) по примеру

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

есть пример

```
<button id="tri" style='display: block;'>add</button>
        <div id="box" style='display: none;' >
```

отслеживаеться по `id`

```
$('#tri').on('click', function(){

                var e = document.getElementById('box');
                var b = document.getElementById('tri');
                if(e.style.display == 'none')
                    $("#box").slideDown();
                b.style.display = 'none';
            })
```

Нужно сделать аналогично, чтобы эта кнопка отслеживала но только
 `class` и `data`

```
<div class="block_view" data-id="52" style='display: none; ></div>
```

Comment: вы про то что селектор надо заменить на `$(".block_view[data-id=52]")` или о чем?

Comment: у меня не работает, а как поместить переменную вместо 52                                         ('body').on('click', '#tri', function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                id = $this.attr('data-id');
            $(".block_view[data-id=52]").style.display = 'block';